# Python Requests Response 404

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I would get access to this website, I get it from another website, https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/algeria/ligue-1/bordj-bou-arreridj-tlemcen/tfvAHu7U/, in the Network section of Developer tools.

Code

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/archive-odds/4urejxv464x0xd4645/18/'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'my user agent'})

print(response)
```

Output `<Response [404]>`

[image]

Comment: When I look at all requests of https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/algeria/ligue-1/bordj-bou-arreridj-tlemcen/tfvAHu7U/ I cannot find `https://www.betexplorer.com/archive-odds/4urejxv464x0xd4645/18/`. Is it from this site?

Comment: If you try to access that URL through your favourite browser, you'll get HTTP 404.

Comment: You have to hover on odds, then will appear the request @AndrejKesely

Comment: I added a picture that show that in Developer Tools the status code is 200 @AndyKnight

Comment: @luka, you are sending a different request than the one the browser sends. You can add some of the headers you see in the devtools and it will go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Referer` HTTP header to obtain correct response:

```py
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.betexplorer.com/archive-odds/4urejxv464x0xd4645/18/"
headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.betexplorer.com",
}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "date": "23.07. 17:36",
        "odd": "1.88",
        "change": "+0.08"
    },
    {
        "date": "23.07. 17:34",
        "odd": "1.80",
        "change": "-0.01"
    },

...
```